# Inner static class with @Configuration picked up by spring scanner for all tests. What is wrong?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

Spring picks up inner `@Configuration` for Test1 from Test2. I need a mocked `IService` in Test2 but a real `ServiceImpl` in Test1. Also I want to have common `TestConfiguration` for all my tests. But I always have mocked IService in both tests. What is wrong?

How I can disable inner configurations picking up for sibling tests?

Here is my code :

ServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
public class SeriviveImpl implements IService {
}
```

TestConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class TestConfiguration {
   // empty
}
```

Test1.java:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
public class Test1 {
    @Autowired
    private IService service;
}
```

Test2.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test2.CustomConfiguration.class, TestConfiguration.class})
public class Test2 {
    @Autowired
    private IService service;

    @Configuration
    static class CustomConfiguration {
        @Bean
        IService service() {
            return mock(IService.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter the inner class from the TestConfiguration @ComponentScan:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
     @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                           value = Test2.CustomConfiguration.class)
})
public class TestConfiguration {
   // empty
}
```

This will prevent it being picked up in Test1.

**EDIT** Or if you have lots of inner configuration you can create your own annotation and filter all these annotated classes from your @ComponentScan:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Configuration
public @interface InnerConfiguration {
}
```

Then use this annotation on your inner classes instead of @Configuration:

```
@InnerConfiguration
    static class CustomConfiguration {
        @Bean
        IService service() {
            return mock(IService.class);
        }
    }
```

and filter these out of your component scan like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
     @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,
                           value = InnerConfiguration.class)
})
public class TestConfiguration {
   // empty
}
```

Comment: Yes I can but it's bad in that way what TestConfiguration knows about Test2 now. TestConfiguration ideally should not know about local subconfigurations.

Comment: It knows because you're component scanning and a @Configuration is a component. That's how Spring works. If you dont want it to pick it up then you have to filter it out. Im pretty sure this is your best option.

Comment: But if I have 20+ tests with custom configurations ? I need to define all of it in common configuration. Is it not ugly?

Comment: Edited my answer for when you have lots of custom configs

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

Since you explicitly use `Test2.CustomConfiguration.class` in `Test2`'s `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, you can remove `@Configuration` annotation from `Test2.CustomConfiguration` and it will not be picked up by `@ComponentScan` during `Test1` run.

This works because:

> To load an ApplicationContext for your tests by using annotated
>   classes (see Java-based container configuration), you can annotate
>   your test class with @ContextConfiguration and configure the classes
>   attribute with an array that contains references to **annotated classes**.

and

> The term “annotated class” can refer to any of the
>   following:
>
> A class annotated with @Configuration.
>
> A component (that is, a class annotated with @Component, @Service,
>   @Repository, or other stereotype annotations).
>
> A JSR-330 compliant class that is annotated with javax.inject
>   annotations.
>
> **Any other class that contains @Bean methods.**

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve that by using `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` annotation to explicitly select the desired implementation. Here is how your code might look like then:

```
...
@Service 
@Qualifier("impl")
public class SeriviveImpl implements IService {}
...
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfiguration.class})
public class Test1 {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("impl")
   private IService service;
}
...
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Test2.CustomConfiguration.class,TestConfiguration.class})
public class Test2 {
   @Autowired
   @Qualifer("mock")
   private IService service;

   @Configuration
   static class CustomConfiguration {
       @Bean
       @Qualifier("mock")
       IService service() { return mock(IService.class); }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think there must be another way. Addition @Qualifier to implementation coz test configurations intersect is not my way.